# Rfc2898DeriveBytes for .NET and Java generate different values

Tags: c#, java, android, .net

I'm trying to use Rfc2898DeriveBytes for Android Java and .NET C# framework to generate key for encryption and decryption process.

The problem is in spite of that the input values are same, I'm getting different keys in .NET and Java.

.NET code:

```
private void btnRfc2898DeriveBytes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[] { 19, 3, 24, 18, 14, 42, 57, 23 };
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes keyGenerator = null;

    keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("somestring", salt, 1000);

    txtRfc2898DeriveBytes.Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(keyGenerator.GetBytes(16));
}
```

Java Code (used in an android application):

```
byte[] salt = new byte[] { 19, 3, 24, 18, 14, 42, 57, 23 };
Rfc2898DeriveBytes keyGenerator = null;
try {
    keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("somestring", salt, 1000);
} catch (InvalidKeyException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("key = ", decodeUTF8(keyGenerator.getBytes(16)));
```

Java Decode Method:

```
String decodeUTF8(byte[] bytes) {
    private final Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    return new String(bytes, UTF8_CHARSET);
}
```

Rfc2898DeriveBytes java class:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * RFC 2898 password derivation compatible with .NET Rfc2898DeriveBytes class. 
 */
public class Rfc2898DeriveBytes {

    private Mac _hmacSha1;
    private byte[] _salt;
    private int _iterationCount;

    private byte[] _buffer = new byte[20];
    private int _bufferStartIndex = 0;
    private int _bufferEndIndex = 0;
    private int _block = 1;


    /**
     * Creates new instance.
     * @param password The password used to derive the key.
     * @param salt The key salt used to derive the key.
     * @param iterations The number of iterations for the operation.
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException HmacSHA1 algorithm cannot be found.
     * @throws InvalidKeyException Salt must be 8 bytes or more. -or- Password cannot be null.
     */
    public Rfc2898DeriveBytes(byte[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        if ((salt == null) || (salt.length < 8)) { throw new InvalidKeyException("Salt must be 8 bytes or more."); }
        if (password == null) { throw new InvalidKeyException("Password cannot be null."); }
        this._salt = salt;
        this._iterationCount = iterations;
        this._hmacSha1 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        this._hmacSha1.init(new SecretKeySpec(password, "HmacSHA1"));
    }

    /**
     * Creates new instance.
     * @param password The password used to derive the key.
     * @param salt The key salt used to derive the key.
     * @param iterations The number of iterations for the operation.
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException HmacSHA1 algorithm cannot be found.
     * @throws InvalidKeyException Salt must be 8 bytes or more. -or- Password cannot be null.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException UTF-8 encoding is not supported. 
     */
    public Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String password, byte[] salt, int iterations) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException  {
        this(password.getBytes("UTF8"), salt, iterations);
    }

    /**
     * Creates new instance.
     * @param password The password used to derive the key.
     * @param salt The key salt used to derive the key.
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException HmacSHA1 algorithm cannot be found.
     * @throws InvalidKeyException Salt must be 8 bytes or more. -or- Password cannot be null.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException UTF-8 encoding is not supported. 
     */
    public Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this(password, salt, 0x3e8);
    }


    /**
     * Returns a pseudo-random key from a password, salt and iteration count.
     * @param count Number of bytes to return.
     * @return Byte array.
     */
    public byte[] getBytes(int count) {
        byte[] result = new byte[count];
        int resultOffset = 0;
        int bufferCount = this._bufferEndIndex - this._bufferStartIndex;

        if (bufferCount > 0) { //if there is some data in buffer
            if (count < bufferCount) { //if there is enough data in buffer
                System.arraycopy(this._buffer, this._bufferStartIndex, result, 0, count);
                this._bufferStartIndex += count;
                return result;
            }
            System.arraycopy(this._buffer, this._bufferStartIndex, result, 0, bufferCount);
            this._bufferStartIndex = this._bufferEndIndex = 0;
            resultOffset += bufferCount;
        }

        while (resultOffset < count) {
            int needCount = count - resultOffset;
            this._buffer = this.func();
            if (needCount > 20) { //we one (or more) additional passes
                System.arraycopy(this._buffer, 0, result, resultOffset, 20);
                resultOffset += 20;
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(this._buffer, 0, result, resultOffset, needCount);
                this._bufferStartIndex = needCount;
                this._bufferEndIndex = 20;
                return result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    private byte[] func() {
        this._hmacSha1.update(this._salt, 0, this._salt.length);
        byte[] tempHash = this._hmacSha1.doFinal(getBytesFromInt(this._block));

        this._hmacSha1.reset();
        byte[] finalHash = tempHash;
        for (int i = 2; i <= this._iterationCount; i++) {
            tempHash = this._hmacSha1.doFinal(tempHash);
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                finalHash[j] = (byte)(finalHash[j] ^ tempHash[j]);
            }
        }
        if (this._block == 2147483647) {
            this._block = -2147483648;
        } else {
            this._block += 1;
        }

        return finalHash;
    }

    private static byte[] getBytesFromInt(int i) {
        return new byte[] { (byte)(i >>> 24), (byte)(i >>> 16), (byte)(i >>> 8), (byte)i };
    }

}
```

Edit:

I also convert it to Hex, but getting different values also.

C# function:

```
public static String encode(byte[] data)
{
    char[] lookup = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
    int i = 0, p = 2, l = data.Length;
    char[] c = new char[l * 2 + 2];
    byte d; c[0] = '0'; c[1] = 'x';
    while (i < l)
    {
        d = data[i++];
        c[p++] = lookup[d / 0x10];
        c[p++] = lookup[d % 0x10];
    }
    return new string(c, 0, c.Length);
}
```

Java method:

```
final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong :( ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I re-solved the issue, the following code generate same values for me in .NET and Java.

.NET code:

```
private void btnKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[] { 172, 137, 25, 56, 156, 100, 136, 211, 84, 67, 96, 10, 24, 111, 112, 137, 3 };
    int iterations = 1024;
    var rfc2898 = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes("_sOme*ShaREd*SecreT", salt, iterations);
    byte[] key = rfc2898.GetBytes(16);
    String keyB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(key);
    txtRfc2898DeriveBytes.Text = keyB64;
}
```

Java code:

```
String password = "_sOme*ShaREd*SecreT";
byte[] salta = new byte[]{-84, -119, 25, 56, -100, 100, -120, -45, 84, 67, 96, 10, 24, 111, 112, -119, 3};
SecretKeyFactory factory = null;
try {
    factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salta, 1024, 128);
SecretKey tmp = null;
try {
    tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
Log.i("The secret Key: " , Base64.encodeToString(secret.getEncoded(), 0 ));
```

Comment: How is the Java salt computed?

Comment: So the problem here is that byte is a SIGNED type in Java, and UNSIGNED in C#, because all types are signed in Java. It actually illustrates why a signed byte type is lunacy IMO. Basically, the Java salt value is simply interpreting numbers larger than 127 as their two's complement representation. e.g.

172 = 0b10101100 -> flip all bits = 01010011, add one: 01010100 = 84 thus you must write -84 in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
txtRfc2898DeriveBytes.Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
    keyGenerator.GetBytes(16));
```

and here:

```
decodeUTF8(keyGenerator.getBytes(16)
```

you are using UTF-8 to decode data into a string that **isn't UTF-8**. Since that does not have a defined output, it is not unreasonable that the two undefined outputs can be different.

Rather than decoding as UTF-8: if you need it as a string, use base-16 (aka "hex") or base-64 to represent the generated bytes. A text encoding (such as UTF-8) is only well-defined when converting string data (in the range of characters supported by that encoding) to/from binary data ***in that encoding***. It is incorrect to "decode" arbitrary binary via a text encoding.

Comment: I convert both to Hex but still getting different values: .NET --> 97DD7946170984F124520B2293B4230C and for Java --> 640CECE99A45BD4F3511C48BBFBE35DD. Need example please.

Comment: @alawibh hmm; vexingly, I suspect your best option is to try both of them against known expected outputs, to see which is playing up...